# "Integer operation result out of range" in cuda source code

Tags: gcc, integer, range

I'm trying to compile a code written using CUDA 3.2 on RHEL 5.6. The relevant portions are

```
extern "C"{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
static uint64_t size = 0;
...
size = 5000 * 1024 * 1024;
printf("sizeof(size) = %d size = %lu\n", sizeof(size), size);
}
```

The code is in a .cu file, and compiled using nvcc. I get the compilation warning that for the line "size = 5000 * 1024 * 1024", the "integer operation result is out of range". The output I got is

```
sizeof(size) = 8 size = 947912704
```

I don't understand why the variable "size" can't represent the value 5242880000 if it's 8-bytes large.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess that each of `5000`, `1024` and `1024` are being treated as `int` literals, the multiplication is being done on `int`s, and then the result being stored in a `uint64_t`. But that's just my intuition. Try suffixing one or more of them with an `L`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Damien commented, the multiplication is being done on *int*. The next code gives the expected result:

```
size = 5000L * 1024 * 1024;
```

This is not related with CUDA or the nvcc compiler which calls to a general purpose C compiler during 'non-CUDA' phases. See *The CUDA Compiler Driver NVCC* doc for more details.